# Error 'float' object is not callable using the derivative function in scipy.misc

Tags: python, scipy, derivative, taylor-series

i am trying to find the coefficients of a Taylor Series using the derivative function of Scipi.misc but i keep getting a error inside the scypy library.

My code:

```
 d_pts = order*2
 if d_pts % 2 == 0: # must be odd and greater than derivative order
   d_pts += 1
 coefficients = []
 for i in range(1, order+1):
   coefficients.append(round((derivative(function, center, n=i, order=d_pts))/math.factorial(i), 5))
 return coefficients
```

The error msg:

```
 <ipython-input-31-c44b369ecec2> in findCoefficients(function, order, center)
     5   coefficients = []
     6   for i in range(1, order+1):
----> 7     coefficients.append(round((derivative(function, center, n=i, order=d_pts))/math.factorial(i), 5))
     8   return coefficients

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/misc/common.py in derivative(func, x0, dx, n, args, order)
   142     ho = order >> 1
   143     for k in range(order):
--> 144         val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
   145     return val / prod((dx,)*n,axis=0)
   146 

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Anyone know how to fix it??

Comment: What is `function`? are you sure it is a function and not a `float`?

Answer (score 0):

looks like instead of function you are passing float value. Make sure that `function` is not the float value but the function.

Also, note that the derivative function is deprecated.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I was indeed passing a float value. I will try it with another approach.